# Redshift WLM Memory Allocation Remainder (0%)

Tags: amazon-redshift

According to the documentation [defining query queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-defining-query-queues.html) "Any unallocated memory is managed by Amazon Redshift and can be temporarily given to a queue if the queue requests additional memory for processing".

I set up:
 - the default queue (60% resources)
 - a specific queue (0% resources)

All queries in the specific queue will hang indefinitely, I would expect redshift to utilise the remaining 40% memory to complete my query.

The reason I want this set up is to divert a monthly batch of many queries to a separate queue that uses **at most** 40% of available resources. This is only required for a short period of time however and I want this memory available for general use.

I tried setting it to 'blank' instead of 0% and this lets queries run but the system table STV_WLM_SERVICE_CLASS_CONFIG implies that the specific queue has the full 40% available (this is unchanging).

Thanks.

Comment: I've never seen any documentation to substantiate this but I once spoke to an AWS Redshift engineer who told me that bit about Redshift giving unallocated memory to other queries was rubbish, i.e. unallocated memory is just unused, not redistributed to other queries. So my advice would be to make sure you are allocating 100% of memory across all your queues.

Comment: For your scenario, maybe look at using the Redshift API to change the wlm memory allocation when needed for this processing, then change it back when completed. WLM memory allocation can be changed dynamically, although it doesn't affect queries that are already running.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I'll look into this. I've managed to make some efficiencies in the queries themselves so WLM may not be required (our traffic is otherwise fairly light). Edit: I think the memory is allocated because queries can still run in the 'blank' queue, setting to zero explicitly seems to enforce that though. Perhaps it distributes the memory over black queues?